# AS3: How do I take a snapshot of a movieclip with a transparent background?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

I am coding in AS3 and I am using BitmapData to take a snapshot of a movieclip.  Is there a way to have the end result BitmapData to support transparency?

How do I take a snapshot of a movieclip without any background?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried the following?

```
// set the transparent property to true
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData( movieClip.width , movieClip.heigth , true );

//pass the movie clip you want to take a snapshot of as a parameter
//to the draw() method
bmd.draw(movieClip);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need set the background color if you need print the movieclips with transparency

If your background is white:

```
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData( movieClip.width , movieClip.heigth , true, 0xFFFFFF );
bmd.draw(movieClip);
```